# C++ dynamically access vector within a vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, tree

I'm making a parse tree for a simple interpreter. Here's the code for a node in my parse tree:

```
struct rtok {
    std::string type;
    std::string val;
};

struct rnode  {
    rtok tok;
    vector<rnode> child;
} node;

vector<rnode> ptree;
```

As you can see, my parse tree is just a "vector of vectors". I also have a function to insert a new node into the parse tree:

```
void add_term(rtok tok) {
    rnode n;
    n.tok = tok;
    ptree.back().child.push_back(n);
}
```

But the problem with this function is, it only inserts items into the child vector of the first vector. i.e. How can I make my function dynamically add more children into the parse tree?
i.e. How can I make my function do something like this:

```
ptree.back().child.back().child.back()...push_back(n)
```

If there's a way to dynamically add `child.back()` that'd be great! Obviously I don't think there is, but I hope this illustrates my point.

Comment: Did you try using a loop or recursion? I recommend you do.

Comment: @user2079303 I thought about it, but I wasn't sure as to how I would dynamically append "child.back()" onto the end each time it looped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this? Sorry if I misunderstood your question..

```
struct rnode  {
  rtok tok;
  vector<rnode> child;
  rnode& back() {
    // if our current node has empty child, return it
    if (child.empty()) return *this;
    // else recursive call this function for the last element of child vector of this node
    else return child.back().back(); // use recursion to get the last non empty vector
  }
  rnode& unrolled_back() {
    // get a pointer to the current struct
    rnode* ptr = this; 
    // if the child has non empty vector, move pointer to its last element
    while (!ptr->child.empty()) {
      // get the address of the last element (we have checked that it has elements already) and assign it to ptr
      ptr = const_cast<rnode*>(&(ptr->child.back())); 
    }
    return *ptr;
  }
  void unrolled_push_back(const rnode& node) {
    // get the last structure that has empty child vector
    auto& last = unrolled_back();
    // add element to it's child
    last.child.push_back(node);
  }

  void push_back(const rnode& node) {
    if (child.empty()) child.push_back(node);
    else return child.back().push_back(node);  // use recursion to get the last non empty vector
  }
} node;

int main() {
  rnode node;
  auto& r1 = node.back();
  assert(&r1 == &node);
  node.push_back(rnode());
  node.push_back(rnode());
  auto& r2 = node.back();
  assert(&r2 == &(node.child.back().child.back()));
  assert(!(&r2 == &(node.child.back())));
  return 0;
}
```

Note, howerever, that this function will crash if the recursion depth will be to high, because stack size is limited. So it is possible to get stackoverflow.

Comment: How big do you think the parse tree would have to be before stackoverflow occurred? Since its part of an interpreter, do you think "normal" programs would crash it?

Comment: @Francis see my update, I added functions unrolled to loop. It's safe to use them, cause they have no recursion at all.

Comment: I apologise if I'm asking a lot because I really appreciate your help, but would you be able to briefly explain your code to me? I'm not that familiar with C++.

Comment: @Francis I added some comments to my code. Have it become more clear? Feel free to ask any questions.